# SAVE NAMES IN FILE

Tags: c++

I want to save several book names to a file and then, after, read them from the file. Like this:

```
char name[100];
cout<<"Enter the name of the book:";
cin.getline(name,100);

ofstream bookname("D:bookname.txt",ios::app);
if(bookname.is_open()){ 
    bookname<<name<<"\n";
    bookname.close();
}
else {
    cout<<"The file does'nt open successfully!\n";
}
```

Read from file:

```
string n[100];
ifstream read("D:bookname.txt");
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    read>>n[i];
read.close();
```

But my problem is when I save names in string `n`.  If the name has space between the letters, it saves separately.

For example, if I enter 'secret garden', it saves two strings 'secret' 'garden'

How to save it as one element?

Comment: Consolidate yourself and your code. Ask clear requirements and what you've been trying to solve them. You have obviously more than one book, so that cries for a loop?

Comment: The head of library enter names of the book and program save them to a text file.and student search book and i want to read them from file and show books.

Comment: I always want to have sweet unicorns around me, farting nice smelling rainbows. Be clear dude! Go for `std::getline()` rather.

Comment: You're confused. This has nothing to do with how it's "saved", and you'd know that if you simply opened the file. In fact, the entire observation is illogical: text files are streams of bytes. How could a text file distinguish between "secret","garden" and "secret garden"?! The problem is that you read from that file wrong, and that's strange because you got it right in the first snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your basic problem is that you're using >> on the input stream and that will read a word at a time. To read a line at a time, you should use getline().

Answer (score 0):

At first, you mustn't save `/n` to the file, it could cause some problems in reading from the file in some cases.

another thing in your code is that you saved the name as character and read it as string,and that is the cause of the problem. the way of saving characters differs from the way of saving strings. When you write string you make one completed line only for writing the sentence.

I thing your code should be like this

Writing:

```
string name;
cout<<"Enter the name of the book:";
getchar();
getline(cin,name);
ofstream bookname("D:bookname.txt",ios::app);
if(bookname.is_open()){    
    bookname<<name;
    bookname.close();
}
else
    cout<<"The file does'nt open successfully!\n";
}
```

Reading

```
string n[100];
int c=0;//the number of times you read a sentence
ifstream read("D:bookname.txt");
while(read)//keap reading from the file until you reach eof.
{
    read>>n[c];
    c++;
}
read.close();
```